# What’s the correct consistency of PVC all purpose cement?

Tags: plumbing

I have a can of Oatey all purpose cement (for PVC, CPVC, and ABS) that’s been sitting in my garage for about 10 months. I don’t remember what it’s supposed to look like. The label says not to use if jelly like. It’s thicker than the blue stuff I’m used to. It’s a light brown color, about the consistency of shampoo. Does this sound normal for this product?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks fairly normal from here.

It's very different from PVC cement, which would be unwise to use at that consistency.